# Why can't I write to the console when the requestedExecutionLevel is requireAdministrator?

Tags: c#, console-application

I wan't to run a windows console application with the requestedExecutionLevel as "requireAdministrator"  but then it isn't printing out the write statements that i specified in my code.

Why doesn't it print when running as admin?

Thanks in advance!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.Write("Hello World" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

And them in the manifest the code is...

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I just Added the code segments for you. nothing special.

Comment: Does `Console.WriteLine` work when the program is not running as administrator? Is your project configured as a Console application (i.e. do you get a console window on-screen?)

Comment: How are you running the program? Inside VS? Double clicking exe? Run...etc.

Comment: I'm running it in windows command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

When you start the command prompt as administrator, then the console writes. However when you start the command promt as ordinary user, then the application will use UAC to request for admin rights and then the console does not write any output

--> start the command prompt as administrator